# How to map Json response in QUASAR

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, quasar

I need to take all persons names, using quasar and vue3.

I need to take all persons data, but I only can take the first object fields like `row.persons[0].name`.

Quasar column data:

```
  {
    name: "personName",
    label: "Name",
    field: rows => rows.persons.name, //here that I can't return both person content
    sortable: true,
    align: "center",
  },
```

Json response

```
{
  "id": 4291,
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": 12485,
      "name": "",
      "email": "",
    },
    {
      "id": 21898,
      "name": "",
      "email": "",
      
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on rows.persons array

for eg

```
rows.persons.map(person=>person.name)
```

will return array containing only the names